# Opening powershell with ShellExecuteEX results in the PS session not importing all available modules

Tags: c++, powershell, qt

Problem: Launching Powershell with ShellExecuteEx is not importing all of the available modules correctly. Or, at least that's how it's presenting. I need to understand why iot's not importing them correctly and how to make the mavailable when going through ShellExecuteEx.

My overall goal is to launch specific predefined commands that require administrator privileges. An example is as follows:

```
New-LocalUser "Apples"
```

This is an arbitrary example but it is something that I tried and failed within the program. It's failing because it doesn't recognize New-LocalUser as a cmdlet. I ran the following command from within the Powershell session I created with ShellExecuteEx:

```
    Get-Command -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name, Source
```

If I run the same command from a powershell that I open up and elevate manually (using my mouse lol). The list is almost the same but is larger. Comparing them shows that the list generated within my c++ program has 128 less commands. For instance, Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts is missing entirely

The function handling this in C++ is:

```
void MainWindow::execute_command()
{
         QString tmp = "$p = \"Test62!""\"; $sec = $p | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;  New-LocalUser \"Microshaft""\" -Password $sec";
         CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
         SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = {0};
         ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
         ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
         ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
         ShExecInfo.lpVerb = "runas";
         ShExecInfo.lpFile = TEXT("powershell.exe");
         ShExecInfo.lpParameters = tmp.toUtf8();
         ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\";
         ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
         ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
         ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
         WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess,INFINITE);
}
```

Sestting:

```
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\";
```

or

```
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
```

makes no difference. The list I generated was pulled by setting

```
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = "Get-Command -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name, Source > C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Downloads\\commands.txt";
```

I wanted to both both lists, or even a single list here but I can't because it exceeds teh character length. Can anyone explain why these commands are missing and how to mnake them available?

UPDATE:

So it's not bringing the commands over because if I install Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts I'm able to use them. It still fails when pushed out from a QString (probably how I'm escaping it). I left the session that I created within the program open. I copy-pasted my command over and, it runs fine.

I don't find the solution I've come up with as acceptable and am sure that I'm missing something. I shouldn't have to install any modules that already exist within the system.  It must be how it's being created or opening for whatever reason it doesn't bring certain modules over. I also tried importing the module but, that didn't work either.

I'm going to Mark it as an answer because it does work. I still hope that someone else can provide me with a better answer or explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I install and import the module within the same command, it works fine. As I said in my update, I don't like or find this answer to be acceptable. It is an answer because it does work. I do hope that someone can assist by providing a better answer and or explanation.

```
QString example = "Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts; Import-Module Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts; Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts > C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Downloads\\commands.txt; $p = \"Test62!""\"; $sec = $p | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;  New-LocalUser \"Microshaft""\" -Password $sec"
```